# shelljs performance is slow

Tags: node.js, shelljs

I have been using shelljs

On my super fast system I execute this:

```
var shell = require('shelljs')
const exec = require('child_process').exec

console.time('shell mktemp -d')
shell.exec('mktemp -d', {silent: true})
console.timeEnd('shell mktemp -d')

console.time('child exec mktemp -d')
exec('mktemp', ['-d'], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('stderr', stderr)
    throw error
  }
  console.log('exec stdout', stdout)
  console.timeEnd('child exec mktemp -d')
})
```

Its giving the following execution times:

> shell mktemp -d: 208.126ms
>
> exec stdout /tmp/tmp.w22tyS5Uyu
>
> child exec mktemp -d: 48.812ms

Why is shelljs 4 times slower? Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you look at the shelljs code to see how it works and what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look to how shelljs is implemented:
[image]

It fully relies on **node.js fs** library. This library is cross platform and written in C++ but not as performant as C language. More generally, you can't have in JS the perfs you get in C...

Another thing, abstraction layers:
you're using exec(Command) where Command is a C tailored (Linux C here I think). The machine creates a thread and executes a command in it.
When using shell.js, there are many mechanisms to ensure cross plateform and keep the abstraction of your command as a function and keep the result as a variable. See the code of exec in shell.js:
https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/blob/master/src/exec.js 
It is not really doing the same thing as your line of code.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Your code example compares async `child_process.exec()` with *sync* `shell.exec()`, which isn't entirely a fair comparison. I think you'll find `shell.exec(..., { async: true })` performs a bit better: this is because *sync* `shell.exec()` does extra work to provide real-time stdio while still capturing stdout/stderr/return code as part of its return value; *async* `shell.exec()` can provide the same feature mostly for free.

Even with `{ silent: true }`, the extra work is still necessary. `shell.exec()` is built on top of `child_process.execSync()`, which only returns stdout. We need to perform the same extra work in order to return return code and stderr.